# M.2 SSD Works, But doesn't show up anywhere

Tags: ssd, fstab

Had a 2 month old 2TB WD Blue M.2 SSD fail in a 20.04 system, read failed and when rebooted it disappeared.  I installed a new one, formatted it, and mounted it without issue.  I can read and write to it, but, it doesn't show up anywhere:

1. df -h             Mountpoint isn't shown
2. fdisk -l          Doesn't show
3. nvme list         Doesn't show

It's mounted in fstab by /dev/disk/by-uuid if that matters.

I just can't figure out why I can't see it anywhere, and why it still works?

Comment: How do you conclude you actually read and write to it, and not to your system disk?

Comment: What commands did you use to format and mount it? If it's actually mounted, it will show up in `df`

Comment: I can read/write to the mountpoint that I defined, but I guess if it doesn't mount it's just writing to the system disk?  It was partitioned with fdisk, then mkfs.ext4.   Is there any way to verify that the system is even seeing the SSD hardware?

Comment: Did you update the /etc/fstab file to specify the UUID of the new partition? The `lsblk` command will show all devices in your machine and if/where they are mounted

Comment: It looks like there must be a hardware issue, there's nothing showing up in lspci, lsblk, fdisk, nothing.  I don't think the system is even seeing the hardware.

Comment: Perhaps check your hardware? It could be an issue with connection between the motherboard and the SSD.